# How do you specify 'Importance' for a message when sending to an Exchange/Outlook user from Gmail?

Tags: gmail

Outlook users can specify the importance of an email message when sending to other Outlook users. This might specifically be for Exchange/Outlook users, I am unsure.

Using Gmail to send a message to an Outlook user (or even another Gmail user) can you specify the importance flag?

If so, how?

Comment: I have tried an experiment a friend using Exchange/Outlook sent an email with High Importance to my Gmail account. There were no visible flags or indications that the message was sent with High Importance.

Comment: changed wording for clarification

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately that feature is not available in the Gmail interface.  This type of thing is what makes me not want to use it as a primary personal service...  I ran across the feature request at one point on the support site, but I can't find the exact one now.  Here's one from the [**Google Apps Help Forums**](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Google+Apps/thread?tid=6a69cc363c203a6d&hl=en).